# JQuery не видит ссылки в сгенерированном коде

Tags: jquery, ссылки

Часть кода сайта (список UL) обновляется с помощью функции jQurey. И в этом коде скрипт не может подхватить для управления ссылки. Эти обе конструкции не срабатывают:

1) `c(".myclass").each(function(d) { c("a", this).each(function(e) {...}) })`

2) `c("a").each(function(e) {...});`

Примечания. При первом отображении кода (список также отображается через функцию jQuery) - все работает правильно, но когда список обновляется (нажатие на определенную ссылку) - перестает подхватывать ссылки... Во втором случае подхватываются все ссылки на странице, кроме тех, что в указанном списке...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это все происходит потому, что Вы меняете структуру DOM, а jquery ничего об этом не говорите.
После каждого изменения структуры DOM нужно производить ре-инициализацию функций, которые навешиваются на изменяемые элементы. Т.е. если Вы подгружаете данные аяксом - то нужно в блоке success заново указывать ваши обработчики.

Comment: Где должен быть такой блок (success ) ?
Объект обновляется функцией 'json_encode' в исходном PHP файле. Функция подхвата ссылок в отдельном js файле..

Comment: дане должнно быть такого... не нужно по success иницировать ничего. Убедитесь, вы когда перестраиваете список, классы им правильно задаете?

live() вам должен помочь!

Comment: Success - это в функции $.ajax(), обычно все ею обновляют контент.  
Насчет live() не уверен - лично не проверял, а насчет перестраивания модели DOM - инфа 100%, сам пару недель назад столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой. Все решилось ре-инициализацией(повторным определением обработчиков после обновления контента).  
Другое дело, если Вы структуру DOM не меняете, а только меняете сам контент, оставляя структуру неизменной.

Comment: Я обновляю только контент. Правда я его обновляю путем замены старых объектов на такие же новые с другим контентом (так запутанно, потому что правлю готовый скрипт). Скорее это тоже что добавлять новые объекты, и для них тоже нужно как-то заново задавать обработчики.

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно заново дать документу просчитать DOM. это можно сделать несколькими способами.
для начала как вы удаляете то что уже ненужно? если просто стирая то оно будет сидеть в моделе и может принести достаточно много неприятностей. убивать советую через 
$('объект').remove();
а добавлять то что получаете по аяксу через

$('объект').append('данные пришедшие в ответе');

Comment: Об этом я и писал в своем сообщении выше. После добавления новых элементов в DOM нужно "показать" jquery, что вы добавили новые элементы)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать

```
$('.myclass').live('click', function(){

});
```

Обработчик сработает на элементах, появившихся после его установки.

Comment: Не срабатывает. Может потому, что эти элементы были, просто они обновлялись.. Зато к статичным элементам (те что были и не обновлялись) тоже перестает срабатывать)..

Comment: Должно срабатывать, а другая какая нибудь функция не перехватывает событие? И как происходит обновление элементов?

Comment: Первое отображение все таки делает PHP функция - там все работает и подхватіваются нужные ссылки. Но эти ссылки обнолвяют часть кода уже посредствам JQuery функции (подключен файл .js):

jQuery(document).ready(function(c) {...
 jQuery.post(FL_Ajax.ajaxurl, f,
    function(i) {c("#mydiv").html(i.data);...}, "json");

И ссылки в этом блоке (#mydiv) не подхватываются даже конструкцией:

c("a").each(function(e) {...});

Comment: $("#mydiv").html(i.data) - заменяеет хтмл код вашего дива, т.е. создаются новые элементы, а старые затираются(даже если у них те же классы и атрибуты, это все равно новый элемент в дом), очень странно, что live(), вам не помогает. Попробуйте, после аякс запроса в success вновь вызвать функцию, которая пройдет по всем ссылкам #mydiv a и вновь навешает им событие клик

Answer (score 0):

Ну попробуйте еще так:

```
$('.myclass').bind('click', function(){
...
});
```

Хотя врятли будет работать, т.к. bind действует только на объекты, которые уже существовали на момент вызова функции. А live как раз срабатывает не только на существующие, но и на те, которые появятся позже.

Comment: Да - не работает...